# Disable obsolete SSL and TLS in Oracle Enterprise Linux

Tags: ssl, oracle-linux

I intend to disable all versions of SSL and TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 from being used due to their insecurity. Can you advise on how i can do this. I have searched online and haven't seen anything of much use.

Comment: Can you just uninstall them from the system (if you want to disable all versions, that is)?